# Format Numbers with possible leading zeroes in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, format, leading-zero

I'm having a hard time to figure out, how to format a range of number correctly.

Lets say I have an array with the following values:

```
array( 1, 2, 001, 02, 012 );
```

How can I change the output of each value to fit the following format?

```
0 => 1

1 => 2

2 => 0.01

3 => 0.2

4 => 0.12
```

I'm not looking for a loop ( this is just for explanation), just a way to format the number correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way PHP interpret Integer you can see you have no leading zeros on Integer ;-)

```
var_dump(array( 1, 2, 001, 02, 012 ));

array(5) {
  [0]=>int(1)
  [1]=>int(2)
  [2]=>int(1)
  [3]=>int(2)
  [4]=>int(10)
}
```

The only way to solve it is converting it to a String.

Comment: because octal `012` is decimal `10`